# Is there a commonly studied number structure with "two" of a given number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

I'm wondering whether there are structures of numbers where there is intuitively "two" of a given number. I have in mind something like what is illustrated in the following example number line segment:

[image]

Do structures such as the one above exist as objects of study in mathematics? What would a structure like this be called?

Comment: Please re-tag as appropriate. I had no idea how to tag this.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Line_with_two_origins  ?

Comment: @IsaacSolomon This quote makes me think this would indeed be an example of the sort of structure I had in mind: "It is the real line with two origins, i.e. with two copies of the origin, wherein although both copies of the origin are separated, arbitrarily small nonzero real numbers approach both these copies." How are these two copies "separated"? Merely conventionally (e.g., different names), or do they differ in their mathematical properties?

Comment: I realize the questions I'm asking about this structure might best go into a separate question. If that's the case, please let me know.

Comment: The construction of this space entails taking two copies of the real line and gluing them together at every point other than the origin. So there really are two different origins (they are separate points). The space itself looks quite funny, because the two origins cannot be placed in disjoint intervals. Any interval around one overlaps with any interval around the other.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon You say the space itself "looks" quite funny...are there any attempts at depicting it visually that you know of? I could easily see why not, but figure it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Think of a ziploc bag which you close by pressing the ends together. Start pressing from the corners, and imagine moving your fingers inwards, connecting opposite sides, slowly approaching the center of the zipper. Visualize that process continuing indefinitely but never reaching the center (maybe your  fingers are too big?). That's the space.

Comment: @IsaacSolomon _Awesome_ description.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking at examples that are the direct product of a ring with its self. The idea of a direct product is that you have a ring, say the integers--you have addition and multiplication. For example, if $\mathbb{Z}$ is the integers, then $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is the direct product. The elements are ordered pairs of integers, and addition and multiplication are defined component wise: $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$,
$(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd)$. Now, you can think of $(1,0)$ as one 'version of one' as if you add and subtract it to its self you get something that is isomorphic to the integers. Similarly for$ (0,1) $and $(1,1)$. Note that $(0,0)$ is the only zero, why?

Also, you can similarily define the direct product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with its self as many times as you'd like--even infinitly many times.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends what you actually want to do with these numbers.  If you want to do arithmetic, and if you want standard rules to apply, then we could perhaps have something like this:
$$1+2=3\,,\ 1+2'=3\quad\Rightarrow\quad 1+2=1+2'\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2=2'$$
and so what you want cannot be done.  On the other hand if you are only interested in the ordering of the "numbers" then you could regard your picture as the [Hasse diagram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HasseDiagram.html) of a partial order.  You might have for example
$$1\le2\quad\hbox{and}\quad 1\le2'\quad\hbox{and}\quad 2\le2$$
and so on, but
$$\hbox{neither}\quad 2\le 2'\quad\hbox{nor}\quad 2'\le2\ .$$

Comment: The reference to Hasse diagrams is especially helpful.